# How to get Document.readyState in puppeteer / headless Chrome?

Tags: node.js, async-await, pdf-generation, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

Using puppeteer, I cannot figure out how to get the document.readyState. I need to wait until the page is loaded before rending a pdf.

```
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
        args: ['--no-sandbox']
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    console.log('Setting HTML content...');

    // Can't POST data with headless chrome, so we have to get the HTML and set the content of the page, then render that to a PDF
    await page.setContent(html);

    // Generates a PDF with 'screen' media type.
    await page.emulateMedia('screen');

    var renderPage = function () {
        return new Promise(async resolve => {

            await page.evaluate((document) => {
                console.log(document);
                const handleDocumentLoaded =  () => {
                    console.log('readyState: ', document.readyState);
                    console.log('Rendering PDF...');
                    Promise.resolve(resolve(page.pdf({ path: thisPDFfileName, format: 'Letter' })));
                };
                if (document.readyState === "loading") {
                    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", handleDocumentLoaded);
                } else {
                    handleDocumentLoaded();
                }
            });

            // I also tried this... no luck
            // setTimeout(async function () {
            //     console.log('Awaiting document...');
            //
            // const handle = await page.evaluateHandle(() => ({window, document}));
            // const properties = await handle.getProperties();
            // const windowHandle = properties.get('window');
            // const documentHandle = properties.get('document');
            // await handle.dispose();
            //
            //     console.log('readyState: ', documentHandle.readyState);
            //     if ("complete" === documentHandle.readyState) {
            //         await documentHandle.dispose();
            //         console.log('readyState: ', doc.readyState);
            //         console.log('Rendering PDF...');
            //         resolve(page.pdf({ path: thisPDFfileName, format: 'Letter' }));
            //     } else {
            //         renderPage();
            //     }
            // }), 250;
        });
    };
    // Delay required to allow page to render JS before creating PDF
    await renderPage();
    await browser.close();
    sendPdfToClient();
```

I tried `evaluateHandle` and could only get the innerHTML, not the document object itself.

What's the correct way to get the `document` object containing `readyState`?

Lastly, should I set a listener for `loaded` or `DOMContentLoaded`, I need to wait until the google maps JS renders the map? I can sent a custom event if need be, since I control the page being rendered.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [`page.goto()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options), you can use the `waitUntil` option to specify when to consider navigation as complete:

The `waitUntil` events include:

> - **`load`** - consider navigation to be finished when the load event is fired.
> - **`domcontentloaded`** - consider navigation to be finished when the `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired.
> - **`networkidle0`** - consider navigation to be finished when there are no more than 0 network connections for at least `500` ms.
> - **`networkidle2`** - consider navigation to be finished when there are no more than 2 network connections for at least `500` ms.

Alternatively, you can use [`page.on()`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_on_eventname_listener) to wait for the [**`'domcontentloaded'`**](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#event-domcontentloaded) event or [**`'load'`**](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#event-load) event.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I was overcomplicated it. Apparently there is already

```
page.once('load', () => console.log('Page loaded!'));
```

which does exactly this. :-D

See detailed documentation here:

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#event-load

There are 2 events which is relavant to your problem

1. `event: 'domcontentloaded'`
2. `event 'load'`